# opencv_traincascade: Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to train opencv_traincascade based on 50 negative pictures, and 50 positive pictures. I have followed the instructions given in this `[thread][1]`. I have tried the different solutions that I found on the web, but couldn't resolve the problem.

I used this command

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt\
>   -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 50\
>   -numNeg 50 -w 80 -h 40 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024\
>   -precalcIdxBufSize 1024
```

I got this error

```
===== TRAINING 19-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   50 : 50
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
```

This is part of the generated text during the training.

```
===== TRAINING 18-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   50 : 50
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    50 : 1.75143e-06
Precalculation time: 14
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|     0.48|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 54 minutes 5 seconds.
```

Comment: try with less Pos than Neg, something like 40:50

Comment: @GPPK when I opened one of the images using cv2.imread(img) , then image.shape, I found that height=410 and width is 500 shoudl i resize the images or should I just change parameters here to -w 500 -h 409. What do you suggest ?

Comment: You definitely should not change -w or -h parameter. Those means the initial size of the window used for the classificator learning. And moreover, for the good accuracy this windows size aspect (proportion w/h) must be the same as the proportion for every cropped object in positive image, because the initial windows size is scaled during classificator learning but aspect is maintaned during whole process.

Comment: As GPPK suggested, try to maintain positive to negative samples ratio around 25%-30% (not 100% as you tried.)

Comment: I have same issue, but @ stage 4, http://answers.opencv.org/question/100858/cascade-training-error-opencv-2413-error-stage-4-train-dataset-for-temp-stage-can-not-be-filled/. :(